# ASP.NET MVC client-side validation stuck in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2, validation, infinite-loop

We're having a problem with client-side validation in an MVC2 project.

There is a view model containing the following property

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

In the corresponding view we have

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "User", FormMethod.Post))
   {
%>
<!-- code removed -->
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserInfo.FirstName)%>
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserInfo.FirstName)%>
<!-- code removed -->
<% } %>
```

The issue arises when the user hits the form submit button and `FirstName` is empty. The browser (IE8 in this case) hangs up, executing JavaScript in an infinite loop.

If we delete the `Required` attribute then the problem does not arise (but of course we don't see the validation error message).

The offending section of JavaScript is in `MicrosoftAjax.debug.js`, in the function

```
var $addHandler = Sys.UI.DomEvent.addHandler = function Sys$UI$DomEvent$addHandler(element, eventName, handler) {
```

in the following section. See the inline comments for details

```
else if (element.attachEvent) {
    browserHandler = function() {
        var e = {}; // we end up back here...
        try {e = Sys.UI.DomElement._getWindow(element).event} catch(ex) {}
        return handler.call(element, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(e)); // ...when this line executes
    }
    element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, browserHandler);
}
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following some investigation, it was found that this issue happens due to the `TextBoxFor`s of the form being within an HTML table (yes, tables for layout - this page is a copy of a ten-year old asp page that was being decomissioned).

The fix for this was to add a workaround of adding `style = "table-layout:fixed;"` to the `<table>` declaration.

Some more details are at http://forums.asp.net/p/1515784/3826207.aspx